# How to write a makefile for python scripts update a database?

Tags: python, sqlite, makefile

I have a bunch of Python scripts that I use in a pipeline to read files, and convert the data to create and populate a sqlite3 database.

I use a makefile to do this; as some of my input files are fairly large, i.e. 5GB and therefore take a considerable time to process, I don't want the makefile to rerun the whole pipeline when I edit just one file.

However, because they all edit the same file, i.e. the database file, they're all in effect phony targets. Is there a way to make it so that make only reruns the targets that have had their files edited?

Here is the makefile that I'm using:

```
.PHONY: all
    all: blogs.db

    blogs.db: create users posts likes blogs blog_likes

    .PHONY: create
    create: create.py
        $(PYTHON) create.py

    .PHONY: users
    users:  users.py
        $(PYTHON) users.py

    .PHONY: posts
    posts:  posts.py
        $(PYTHON) posts.py

    .PHONY: likes
    likes:  likes.py
        $(PYTHON) likes.py

    .PHONY: blogs
    blogs:  blogs.py
        $(PYTHON) blogs.py

    .PHONY: blog_likes
    blog_likes: blog_likes.py
        $(PYTHON) blog_likes.py
```

Comment: Have you tried making them produce a "temp" target file to indicate they have already been built (just brainstorming)?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to rerun a script when *the script itself* has changed? Or when something has modified that script's *input file(s)*? And if the latter, do you know beforehand which files each script will read?

Comment: Thankfully the input files are static and won't be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need dummy files, provided nothing other than these scripts is modifying the database:

```
SCRIPTS = create.py users.py posts.py likes.py blogs.py blog_likes.py

.PHONY: all
all: blogs.db

blogs.db: $(SCRIPTS)
    @for s in $?; do $(PYTHON) $$s; done
```

Comment: Nice. Verified that this works. It works because [$?](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) expands to "all of the dependencies that have changed since the file was built." And $$ is simply an escape mechanism, meaning it's a Bash $ and not a Makefile $.

Answer (score 1):

If the targets are phony, they will rebuild every time someone depends upon them. Instead have each target be a real target that creates a dummy file, as @jdi said, to indicate that they have been built. Then they will be re-run when the .py file changes only.

```
blogs.db: create.dummy users.dummy posts.dummy likes.dummy blogs.dummy \
    blog_likes.dummy

create.dummy: create.py
    $(PYTHON) create.py
    touch create.dummy

etc...
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, unfortunately I suspected as much, but it does strike me as fairly inelegant :(...

Comment: It's sort of inelegant, but it's also quite unavoidable. I don't even know if any of the more trendy make systems could make it easier. The bottom line is that you need to keep some state about "has create.py contributed to blogs.db since it was last updated?" and that means you need a timestamp that records the last time create.py contributed to blogs.db. The only way Make understands timestamps is by looking at file mtime, so you need another file.